# API constant values of InputType

Tags: android, android-inputtype

My app is accessing the `InputType` value of EditTexts. Sometimes this produces unexpected behavior. Digging deeper in the issue I found several things which look like undesired behavior:

- [TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD), [TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_URI](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_URI) as well as [TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_DATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_DATE) all have the same value of 16
- `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD` (0x80) & `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER` (0xb0) == 0x80 == `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD`, i.e. if a field has the `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER` it also has `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD` which seems incorrect. However, `bitwise and` (&) should be used to check flags because input types are usually combined using `|`, as suggested in all examples on https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html

Is this a weakness in the Android API? Or am I understanding this totally wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the combination of several values with `|` in the examples only combines class, variation and flags, but never several variations. Given a certain type, this also differentiates TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD, TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_URI and TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_DATE.
So the correct way of accessing these values is checking for a certain class and then for a variation using `(inputType & TYPE_MASK_VARIATION) == inputTypeToCheckFor`.